# Disable HTTP traffic on my entire computer

Tags: network

Is it possible to prevent all HTTP (or any other unencrypted protocol) on my mac while connected to an insecure network (any network without a password)?

In Chrome, I'm able to use the extension HTTPS Anywhere and click "Block all HTTP requests", however other programs that might be running in the background could potentially be sending HTTP requests without my knowledge.

Comment: A password protected network isn't necessarily secure (Wi-FI (WPA/WEP) in an internet café) as well as a non-password protected isn't necessarily insecure (ssh-tunnel/VPN). Please specify your problem/question. Not to speak of other unencrypted protocols (e.g. DNS). BTW It's no problem to block all http traffic with a 3rd-party tool like Little Snitch.

Comment: @klanomath I was referring to networks that I connected to without knowing the source of (such as xfinitywifi, Starbucks Wifi, ATTWifi, etc)

Comment: I achieve what you're trying to do with Little Snitch: I have 3 profiles that switch automatically according to the connected network name. One allows all traffic to pass through, it's used when I'm connected to my Home WiFi or to a trusted VPN. The second one only allows traffic on port 443 (mainly used for HTTPS) and I use it on open networks. Finally, I have a third profile that only allows Safari and Emails for when I'm tethered to my iPhone (it saves bandwidth by avoiding accidental iCloud/iTunes/Dropbox/... downloads).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an application called [SSL Enforcer](https://www.sslenforcer.com) (currently in beta) and works system-wide. It has 2 main modes of operation:

- "Strict Mode" which *forces* https connections.
- "Best Effort Mode" which will redirect to https when available.

I've tried it before, and found that when I set it to *Strict Mode* it broke some websites with mixed content. Here are the applications "Key Features" via its webpage:

> Works for all apps including browsers, plug-ins and any other Internet clients.
>
> No data leaks. Blocks unsecure connections on the system level starting from the very first request.
>
> Switches to secure connections (HTTPS) automatically if available.
>   Flexible rules based on application name, target host and port.
>
> Does not use a tunnel or proxy server. Your traffic goes directly to the target with maximum speed.

Comment: OP wanted this to happen only when connected to specific WiFi networks (or when NOT connected to specific WiFi networks). Sounds like that isn't in SSL Enforcer; sounds like they should add it!

Comment: @DanielGriscom Yes, I am aware that it really isn't an automated solution, but it is free and simpler than setting up rules in Little Snitch or Hands Off!

Comment: Thank you, I'll just remember to enable/disable this whenever I connect to a new network.

Comment: To be clear, it does look like a good solution (absent the automation). I'd recommend Little Snitch anyway; it's amazing how many apps Phone Home.

Answer (score 2):

Use a tool such as [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch) or [Hands Off](https://www.oneperiodic.com/products/handsoff/) to block all outgoing connections to remote machines' port 80 and port 443. As @LaX notes, Little Snitch can switch profiles based on the network name; I expect Hands Off can do so as well.

**Edit:** you specified "any other unencrypted protocol". So, you wouldn't want to block port 443, which is HTTPS, or encrypted. But, if you really wish "any other unencrypted protocol" to be blocked, you're going to have to block just about all outgoing traffic. In Little Snitch, you could set up two rules: "block all outgoing traffic", and "allow outgoing port 443 traffic"; the more specific rule would override the more general rule. You might also include an exception for port 22 (ssh).

Comment: You need a pretty good and bloated `hosts` file if you allow 443/22 only ;-)